# How to convert a rule to a memorization function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, replacement

Any suggestion on how to convert list of rules to a memorization function. My actual set of rules are about 3000, so doing it manually will be difficult.

```
rules1 = {a -> Sin[t], b -> (a*Cos[t])/(2 + a), 
 c -> b^2 + a*Sin[t] + 1, d -> c^2 + b*Cos[t] - c*b};

 newrulesFunc=rules1 /. {a -> a[t], 
          b -> b[t], c -> c[t], 
              d -> d[t]}
```

For which i got the result as

```
 {a[t] -> Sin[t], b[t] -> 
   (a[t]*Cos[t])/(2 + a[t]), 
  c[t] -> 1 + b[t]^2 + 
    a[t]*Sin[t], d[t] -> 
   (-b[t])*c[t] + c[t]^2 + 
    b[t]*Cos[t]}
```

I got struck here.
How to proceed so that I can get to

```
{a[t_] := a[t] = Sin[t], 
  b[t_] := b[t] = 
    (a[t]*Cos[t])/(2 + a[t]), 
  c[t_] := c[t] = 
    1 + b[t]^2 + a[t]*Sin[t], 
  d[t_] := d[t] = 
    (-b[t])*c[t] + c[t]^2 + 
     b[t]*Cos[t]}
```

Thanking you all in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the methods below basically create for each rule `k -> g[a, b, c,...]` a code of the form

```
mem : k[t_] := mem = g[a[t], b[t], c[t],...]
```

which is then executed.  The usage is the same for all three:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, mem];
toMemo[t][rules1]
```

They also work for multivariate definitions, such as `toMemo[s, t][rules]`.

*Method 1*

```
toMemo[args___][rules_] := 
  With[{keypat = Alternatives @@ Keys[rules], 
    a = Sequence @@ Function[x, x_, Listable][{args}]
    },
   (Insert[Hold[mem : #1[a], Set[mem]],
         #2 /. w : keypat :> w[args],
         {2, -1}] & @@@ rules) /. Hold -> SetDelayed;
   ];
```

*Method 2*

```
toMemo[args___][rules_] := 
  With[{k = Keys@rules, v = Values@rules, 
    a = Sequence @@ Function[x, x_, Listable][{args}]},
   ReleaseHold@MapThread[
      Hold@(mem : #1[a] := mem = #2) &,
      {k, v /. f : Alternatives @@ k :> f[args]}
      ];
   ];
```

*Method 3*

```
toMemo[args___][rules_] := 
  With[{k = Keys@rules, a = Function[x, x_, Listable][{args}]},
   Block[{Set, SetDelayed},
      rules /.  HoldPattern[f_ -> body_] :>
        ((mem : f @@ a := mem = #) &@
          (body /. v : Alternatives @@ k :> v[args]))
      ] // Identity;
   ];
```

Comment: OP, these methods would be much more general than my suggested solution, which is more like a hack for your specific case. At least I got to show you the `With[{x=x} ` trick :)

Comment: Hi, @ Michael E2. I'm unable to apply your method to above "rule1". Would you provide how to use your method. Show how the output looks like. And also would you check method 1 there seems to be some error is placing brackets.

Comment: @GummalaNavneeth The usage is shown in the second code block, `toMemo[t][rules1]`.  There is no output.  It just makes definitions. You can inspect them with `? a` etc.: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mxbVX.png  (Often when things don't work for one person, but work for another, there are latent definitions lurking in the kernel that are messing things up.  Either try restarting the kernel, or apply `ClearAll[toMemo, a,b,c,d,t]` and maybe clear some other things that might be interfering.)

Answer (score 5):

Does this do what you want?

```
 {a[t] -> Sin[t], b[t] -> 
   (a[t]*Cos[t])/(2 + a[t]), 
  c[t] -> 1 + b[t]^2 + 
    a[t]*Sin[t], d[t] -> 
   (-b[t])*c[t] + c[t]^2 + 
    b[t]*Cos[t]} /. {(name_[arg_] -> val_) :> 
   With[{name = name}, (name[dummy_] := 
      name[dummy] = With[{arg = dummy}, val])]}
```

After executing this, we can call

```
a[1]; b[1]; c[1]; d[1];
```

If we now check their `DownValues` with e.g. `?a` or `DownValues[a]` we find that results have been memoized.

Note that the order in which these functions are called matters for what is memoized. If we call e.g. `b[2]` before we have called `a[2]` then the `DownValues` for `b` will contain calls to `a` for which no appropriate memoization has occured, so that will take away the benefit of memoization.