# How to directly convert the solution of a recursive equation into a function expression?

Tags: function-construction, rule, difference-equations

```
Clear["Global`*"]
RSolve[{p[i] == 2/5 p[i - 1] + 1/2 p[i] + 1/10 p[i + 1], p[0] == 0, 
   p[8] == 1}, p[i], i] // FullSimplify
```

According to the above code get the result:

```
{{p[i] -> (-1 + 4^i)/65535}}
```

Furthermore,How to directly convert the solution of a recursive equation into a function expression?

That is to say the following result:

```
{{p[i] -> (-1 + 4^i)/65535}}
```

how to Converted to this function format:

```
p[i_] = (-1 + 4^i)/65535
```

or

```
p[i_] := (-1 + 4^i)/65535
```

The purpose of this conversion is to directly calculate the function value through the function expression

such as:

```
p[4]
p[8]
```

and so on!

Comment: Why not simply `psol = RSolveValue[{p[i] == 2/5  p[i - 1] + 1/2  p[i] + 1/10  p[i + 1], p[0] == 0,  p[8] == 1}, p, i]`?

Comment: The purpose of this conversion is to directly calculate the function value through the function expression

such as:

p[4]
p[8]
and so on!

Comment: Execute my code and then try `psol[4]` and `psol[8]` and so on, and read document of `Function` carefully.

Comment: I don't know who ordered a close? Can you explain the reason?

Comment: Clear["Global`*"]
p = RSolveValue[{p[i] == 2/5 p[i - 1] + 1/2 p[i] + 1/10 p[i + 1], 
   p[0] == 0, p[8] == 1}, p, i]

Comment: @xzczd This method can solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221269/how-to-convert-a-rule-to-a-memorization-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSolve returns one ore more rules. To convert the first rule to a function, you may write:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
fun[i_] = 
 p[i] /. RSolve[{p[i] == 2/5 p[i - 1] + 1/2 p[i] + 1/10 p[i + 1], 
     p[0] == 0, p[8] == 1}, p[i], i][[1]] // FullSimplify

(-1 + 4^i)/65535
```

If RSolve returns2 rules, you would write:

```
{fun1[i_],fun2[i_]}=p[i] /.  RSolve[...]
```